# Who do you know the time working of Apple review team?

Tags: appstore-approval

I've submitted my app to Apple review (from 11/24 to now) about 9 days ago.I've just received metadata rejected from Apple review team.
I've added metadata that Apple required this morning and resubmit for review
But I forget sent a reply from Resolution center :(..
I am still waiting review to approve my app from Apple...
I feel worry if I have to waiting next 9 days ...
Do you know the time working of Apple review team?
How long until back In Review after “Metadata Rejected”?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking about the business hours of a company's resources. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

As per [apple](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/):
**App Review Status**

> Once you've submitted your app for review, you can view its status in
>   the My Apps section of iTunes Connect or on the iTunes Connect App for
>   iPhone and iPad. Review times may vary by app. On average, 50% of apps
>   are reviewed in 24 hours and over 90% are reviewed in 48 hours. If
>   your submission is incomplete, review times may be further delayed or
>   your app may be rejected. Once your app has been reviewed, its status
>   will be updated and you will be notified. For details on viewing and
>   changing your app’s status, read the

Comment: It's depending on Application Traffic, but as per my experience it will take 24-48 hours.

Comment: ah. I forgot send a reply at the Resolution Center when I re-submitted for review. Do they know it has just a metadata update not binary?

Comment: if you have any change related to application build then you need to upload new build

Comment: just metadata update not new build but I forgot send a reply at the Resolution Center when I re-submitted for review. Do they understand it has just a metadata update not binary?

Comment: Some times they took time..Apple took 6 days to take my app in review.

Comment: It won't be an issue if you change meta data after they rejected your app for meta data.

Comment: Yes , Its okay if you forgot to reply, they will understand.